# tunnel using autossh behaving differently than the exact same command using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, tunneling

I am trying to set up a double-ssh tunnel between two hosts, so I can proxy traffic through it.

Using the normal SSH command, I have gotten the following to work:

```
    ssh -t -L2000:localhost:2000 user@host1 ssh -D 2000 differentuser@host2
```

My understanding of this command is "forward my local port 2000 to port 2000 on the first remote host, then treat the local port 2000 on the first remote host as a SOCKS proxy to the second remote host". I have copied the relevant public keys to each host so that each step requires no password.

This works fine, until one of the connections drops. I then tried using autossh to get around this, eg:

```
    autossh -t -L2000:localhost:2000 user@host1 autossh -D 2000 differentuser@host2
```

But it kept displaying:

```
    bind: Address already in use
    channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 2000
```

I did get a shell prompt from the second host however, but the tunnel was not working. I then tried using different ports between the first and second hosts like so:

```
    autossh -t -L2000:localhost:2001 user@host1 autossh -D 2001 differentuser@host2
```

This produced no errors, but the resulting tunnel still did not work.
Doing the steps manually, eg:

```
    autossh -L2000:localhost:2000 user@host1
```

and then on host 1:

```
    autossh -D 2000 differentuser@host2
```

works perfectly. I would, however, like to do it all using one command so I can script it.

Can anyone help me get autossh to perform the same behaviour as regular ssh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question. I've just done a bit of testing and it looks like `ssh` and `autossh` treat the final "command" part of the command line differently. For example:

```
$ ssh 0 ls -ld /tmp
tom@0's password: 
drwxrwxrwt 16 root root 4096 2011-06-05 11:17 /tmp
$ autossh 0 ls -ld /tmp
d@'s password:
```

`autossh` is parsing the final command and interpreting the flags, rather than leaving them alone like `ssh` does. In this case, it interprets `-l` as the flag to specify the remote user. In your case, it is interpreting the `-D` as an option to the first `autossh`, not the second.

You can get around this by putting the command part in quotes. In your example:

```
autossh -t -L2000:localhost:2000 user@host1 "autossh -D 2000 differentuser@host2"
```